# More cores are better for Monero CPU mining?

Tags: mining, cpu-mining, mining-theory, mining-hardware

Considering that I have the same intel processor, but one has 4 cores and the other has 8 cores. It will mine better or its the same?

I know that several parameters are important but consider that every other parameter is the same and the cores are the only difference, which is better?

Comment: Basically what I'm asking is if monero mining takes advantage of having several cores, or it depends on the specific mining software used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say that it will not automatically mine better. What is important is the cache size of the CPU. You need 2 MB for one thread.

Let's say your cache is 4 MB and you have 8 cores, you still can only mine with 2 threads - or at least having more cores doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your CPU has enough cache to handle the software. Each thread of the mining software is run on a separate core of the processor so you will be running twice as many threads thus if each core is identical you will have double the hashrate. This may not be observed due to a lack of cache on a CPU of which a thread require 2MB of.

Answer (score 0):

Definetelly It ll mine much better, I try to mine with an I7 dualcore I get 60H/S with an I5 quadcore I get 140H/S

Answer (score -1):

It will mine better. You are applying more computing resources.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your answer please? Perhaps refer to existing benchmarks or resources.